# Persuade antonym - unintentional

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

## Background

Imagine you are a presidential candidate. You have a potential winning policy idea. Now is time to finesse the details. Your fundamental goal is persuade as many people as possible about your policy idea.

Now, you know that some people will be turned off by it, but you believe your messaging can help outnumber those that are turned off. Maybe you could say that this is all intentional at this point. You know what kinds of people you will never receive their support from, and you know what people could join you. This seems all intentional so far.

## Question

My question deals with the unintentional losses. Maybe you chose an incorrect word or phrase. Turns out you lost people. Maybe gaffes would fall under a similar idea, but they aren't my main focus (just to help explain the idea).

Your goal was to **persuade** people, but you did the **opposite**, **unintentionally**.

What is a word that means that? This can be a word or phrase.

## What I did

I thought a good word was **dissuade**, and I used that. But the more I think about it, it appears that dissuade is an intentional act. You are intentionally persuading someone to not do something. That is what dissuade appears to mean. However, that is intentional, and I am looking for unintentional.

In particular, I wrote something like this, "...add just one word and you can dissuade many, but you also persuade many others." Just to reiterate, I was going for intentionally to unintentionally as concise as possible.

Comment: Botched rollout, or unintentionally dissuasive. I don't think there's a single word solution to this. Anti-charismatic is just reaching too far.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger but I am correct in that dissuade is intentional, right?

Comment: @ Christopher Rucinski: Usually That's true, but consider the sentence "The President's speech dissuaded as many voters as it persuaded". Surely the President had one intent, and not the other, so one of the two must be unintended. Adding another word to clarify intent is safest.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger where did you get that quote from? Maybe by including both your indirectly assume unintentionality, but when you just use dissuade alone, then it is intentional???

Comment: @ Christopher Rucinski - It's simply a valid sentence I slapped together, and delineated with quotemarks. By presuming the speaker has one goal or the other, their large failure rate has to be unintended.

Answer (score 2):

The word often used for this is **alienate**:

> cause (someone) to become unsympathetic or hostile. —[Oxford Dictionaries/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alienate)

It is used extremely often to describe the act of accidentally losing voters:

- [How to Alienate Voters and Lose Elections](https://spectator.org/how-to-alienate-voters-and-lose-elections/)
- [Trump's alienation of younger voters is a generational gamble for GOP](https://www.cnn.com/2018/12/04/politics/trumps-alienation-of-younger-voters-is-a-generational-gamble-for-gop/index.html)
- [Alienated voters 'don't feel Brexit will help them retake control' over decision making](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/01/21/alienated-voters-dont-feel-brexit-will-help-retake-control-decision/)

Answer (score 1):

"A gaffe is when a politician unintentionally tells the truth."
——Michael Kinsley

Comment: I added a change to express my desire more fully. I don't know if a gaffe is directly related, but it has the same effect (I think) of possibly loading support unintentionally. Not sure if that is "wide-spread"  enough of a word

Comment: Sorry for the digression.  You mentioned gaffe, and it reminded me of the rather famous witticism by an American pundit.  Not very to-the-point, but amusing.